# how to get input field value whatever user type?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to get input field value whatever user type in input field.using this input `text` I am trying to fetch data from server  and display on dropdown .then select value from dropdown

Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-7iy8l

API LINK
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-clearable-multiple

```
 <Dropdown
    clearable
    fluid
    multiple
    search
    selection
    options={countryOptions}
    placeholder='Select Country'
  />
```

Comment: use `onSearchChange` Props of react-semantic-ui ... 

`onSearchChange={(event) => {console.log(event.target.value)}}`

Answer (score -3):

If you need to fetch selected value then you need to use `e.target.textContent` and by using that you can call API from that function also you can store that value in state or variable as per your needs.

```
export default class DropdownExampleClearableMultiple extends React.Component {
  getValue = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        clearable
        fluid
        multiple
        search
        selection
        options={countryOptions}
        placeholder="Select Country"
        onChange={this.getValue}
      />
    );
  }
```